# How to stub headless_chrome requisitions with web_mock on src attributes on img tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, webmock, system-testing

I'm trying to use Webmock to stub headless chrome requisitions. I simply want to test the following:

Given a select and a carousel tags (the carousel is implemented using Swiper), if I change the select tag, the current showing image of the carousel has to change accordingly. For that, I'm using VueJS. An example of that in jQuery would be:

```
$(document).on('load', function() {
  $('.current-carousel-image').src = "https://something.com/some-image"
})
```

How can I stub these requests from src attribute in an img tag?

I'm using Webmock, so essentially I tried this:

```
test 'test something' do
  stub_request(:any, /host.com.br/)
  visit products_path(product)

  [...]

  find('select[data-grass="material-filter"]').find(:xpath, 'option[2]').select_option

  [...]
end
```

being `host.com.br` the service that provides the images I need.

this seems to work when I try using `Net::HTTP` methods, however, in my system test, the requisitions keep returning a 400 status (that's what's expected given that I'm using FactoryBot to generate the data that I use in the page being tested, but the service that provides the images I use are prepared to actual models in my production database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't stub those using WebMock. WebMock can only stub requests your application makes - it can't do anything with requests the browser makes.

To stub/mock requests made by the browser you need to use a programmable proxy. One you may want to look at is [PuffingBilly](https://github.com/oesmith/puffing-billy)

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for pointing this gem. It seems to be what I'm looking for but I'm having trouble with its setup for Rails System Test. Could you please check this other question of mine? Thanks a lot!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56854435/how-to-setup-puffing-billy-to-rails-system-test