# How to setup puffing-billy to Rails System Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mocking, system-testing

I'm trying to setup puffing-billy to work with Rails System Test. Since it uses Capybara for that, I tried all the documented Capybara solutions here, but didn't seem to get it correctly setup.

System Test generates an `application_system_test_case.rb` for config stuff. Here's how it looks like:

```
require "test_helper"
require 'billy'

class ApplicationSystemTestCase < ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase
  driven_by :selenium, using: :headless_chrome, screen_size: [1400, 1400]

  Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome_billy
  Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver

  WebMock.allow_net_connect!
end
```

And the actual test file looks like this:

```
require "application_system_test_case"

class PromotionsTest < ApplicationSystemTestCase
  include ApplicationHelper

  make_my_diffs_pretty!
  Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 3
  Capybara.configure do |config|
    config.app_host = "http://dev.myapp.com"
  end

  test 'Stub test' do
    proxy.stub('http://www.google.com/').and_return(:text => "I'm not Google!")

    visit 'http://www.google.com/'
  end
end
```

But then when I run the tests:
`NameError: undefined local variable or method 'proxy' for #<PromotionsTest:0x00007fd357450c90>`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC puffing-billy doesn't install helpers for system tests so you'll need to access the proxy via the Billy namespace

```
Billy.proxy.stub(...)
```

Also, system tests override `javascript_driver',`current_driver`, etc so you need to specify the driver you want to use via`driven_by`

```
driven_by :selenium, using: :selenium_chrome_billy
```

Note: I'm away from my main computer so this is all off the top of my head and may not be 100% correct but should put you on the right path.